# Decorator to add key parameter support to an existing sort function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, meta-programming

## Preface

[`sorted` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) has `key` keyword-only parameter. Most of the custom implementations like the following for [*heapsort* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)

```
import heapq
import itertools
from typing import (Iterable,
                    TypeVar)

Domain = TypeVar('Domain')


def heapsort(iterable: Iterable[Domain]) -> Iterable[Domain]:
    heap = []
    for element in iterable:
        heapq.heappush(heap, element)
    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, len(heap)):
        yield heapq.heappop(heap)
```

has no `key` parameter support. I thought of a decorator that will add `key` parameter support in the next fashion

```
from functools import wraps
from operator import itemgetter
from typing import (Callable,
                    Iterable,
                    Optional,
                    TypeVar)

Domain = TypeVar('Domain')
Sortable = TypeVar('Sortable')


def with_key(plain: Callable[[Iterable[Sortable]], Iterable[Sortable]]
             ) -> Callable[..., Iterable[Domain]]:
    @wraps(plain)
    def implementation(iterable: Iterable[Domain],
                       *,
                       key: Optional[Callable[[Domain], Sortable]] = None
                       ) -> Iterable[Domain]:
        if key is None:
            yield from plain(iterable)
            return
        yield from map(itemgetter(2),
                       plain((key(element), index, element)
                             for index, element in enumerate(iterable)))

    return implementation
```

and after that used like

```
>>> heapsort_with_key = with_key(heapsort)
>>> list(heapsort_with_key(range(10), key=lambda x: -x))
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

## Problem

I wonder if there is a better way (e.g. in terms of memory efficiency) of adding `key` parameter? Does anyone know how it is implemented in `sorted`?

Answer (score 1):

Python is open-source, and all the source code in the GitHub repository [python/cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython). For a great deal of the built-ins, they can be found in [cpython/Python/bltinmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c)
. In the current revision, the beginning of the sorted function definitions is found at [line 2175](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8ac658114dec4964479baecfbc439fceb40eaa79/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2175), and the actual function itself is found at [line 2201](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8ac658114dec4964479baecfbc439fceb40eaa79/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2201).

However, I'm not sure that knowing the implementation of sorted can help you too much with optimizing heapsort, because sorted uses [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

I can make a suggestion: decorators will always add overhead, and particularly in a case like this, it's probably better to just make a new version of the function that integrates the key parameter with the original function, though this answer might miss the entire point of your question.

Comment: I'm writing a library and part of it deals with sorting, so I've thought about an unique way for users to register their own sorting algorithms implementations and simply decorating them to have `key` parameter support "for free"

Comment: my answer about built-in `sorted` was how it deals with `key` parameter internally, I'm not so experienced with `CPython` (and `C` in general) and can't see anything in given source lines related to `key` parameter